# I keep getting an error that my require_once is not pointing to the right path. But it is?

Tags: php

I keep getting this error

> Warning: require_once(../config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/busapp/php/register.php on line 11 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../config.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/busapp/php/register.php on line 11

Here is a picture of my file structure

[image: picture of my file structure]

The `register.php` file is just inside `php/`

and my `register.php` file contains `require_once('../config.php');`

It appears to not be jumping up a folder, why is that?

Comment: ../config.php is relative to each of the entries in include_path in turn until it's found.... where the first entry (.) is the current working directory, not necessarily the directory with the file that executes the include

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry I don't really understand could you explain a little better?

Comment: When you do a /relative/ include (ie not beginning with /), PHP searches for the file relative to each directory listed in the include path in turn until it finds the file, or doesn't locate it relative to any of those directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems here `/var/www/busapp/php/register.php` you are asking for the `config.php` file inside the `PHP` folder, but in reality, the `config.php` file is in your root, so, you have to adjust `Line 11` in your register.php to `/var/www/busapp/register.php`

Comment: But line 11 says `require_once('../config.php');` copy pasted straight from the `register.php` file, it is asking to jump up one with ../ so it should be looking in the parent folder, but it is taking the ../config.php literally.

Comment: You should try with one `.` or try requiring the full path of the file, and it will give you insight about how to solve the problem

Comment: Thanks, for some reason adding . instead of .. fixed my problem, why is that?

Comment: Because, dots represent directories. I'am glad it worked out for ya :)